# Data loading too slow here, need help in Optimization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-hooks

I wrote this piece of code, but the data loading is very slow in this. I am trying to optimise this or trying to keep the code as simple as possible(Performance wise). So can anyone help me write the code in a more optimised way.

```
const countAndOrganizeEvents = (eventData) => {
      const coursesByDate = {};
      eventData.forEach(({ startProgramDates, endProgramDates, courseName, startTime, endTime, format }) => {  
        const startDate = parse(startProgramDates, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());  
        const endDate = parse(endProgramDates, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());  
     
        // Iterate through each day between start and end dates  
        for (let currentDay = startDate; isBefore(currentDay, endDate) || isEqual(currentDay, endDate); currentDay = addDays(currentDay, 1)) {  
          const formattedDate = currentDay.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' }).split('/').join('-');  
          if (!coursesByDate[formattedDate]) {  
            coursesByDate[formattedDate] = {  
              startProgramDates,  
              endProgramDates,  
              courses: [],  
            };  
          }  
          coursesByDate[formattedDate].courses.push({  
            courseName,
            startProgramDates,  
            endProgramDates,  
            startTime,  
            endTime,  
            format,  
          });  
        }  
      });  
     
      const coursesCountByDate = Object.entries(coursesByDate).map(([date, { courses }]) => ({  
        date,
        courseCount: courses.length,  
        courses,  
      }));
  
      setEventsCountandDate(coursesCountByDate);
      console.log(eventsCountandDate);
    };
    useEffect(() => {  
      const fetchData = async () => {  
        try {  
          const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/search-course?date=09-02-2024');  
          const eventData = response.data.Table1;  
          countAndOrganizeEvents(eventData);  
        } catch (error) {  
          console.error('Unable to fetch events count and details', error);  
        }  
      };  
      if (daySelected) {  
        fetchData();  
      }  
    }, [countAndOrganizeEvents, daySelected]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that your script engages in substantial operations within the loop for each occurrence, particularly when handling dates and formatting. Below are a few recommendations to refine the script:

**Avoid Repetitive Date Parsing**: Instead of parsing start and end dates repeatedly for every occurrence, parse them once outside the loop.

**Deploy a Set for Swift Date Verification**: Utilize a Set to monitor distinct dates, enhancing the speed of verification.

**Consolidate DOM Manipulation**: Instead of altering the state (setEventsCountandDate) within the loop for each date, aggregate the modifications and execute them collectively after the loop.

Presented here is an enhanced iteration of your script:

```js
const countAndOrganizeEvents = (eventData) => {
  const coursesByDate = {};
  const coursesCountByDate = [];

  eventData.forEach(({ startProgramDates, endProgramDates, courseName, startTime, endTime, format }) => {
    const startDate = parse(startProgramDates, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());
    const endDate = parse(endProgramDates, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());

    const uniqueDates = new Set(); // Use a Set for faster existence check

    for (let currentDay = startDate; isBefore(currentDay, endDate) || isEqual(currentDay, endDate); currentDay = addDays(currentDay, 1)) {
      const formattedDate = currentDay.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' }).split('/').join('-');

      if (!uniqueDates.has(formattedDate)) { // Check if the date already exists
        uniqueDates.add(formattedDate);

        if (!coursesByDate[formattedDate]) {
          coursesByDate[formattedDate] = {
            startProgramDates,
            endProgramDates,
            courses: [],
          };
        }

        coursesByDate[formattedDate].courses.push({
          courseName,
          startProgramDates,
          endProgramDates,
          startTime,
          endTime,
          format,
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // Batch state update outside the loop
  const updatedCoursesCountByDate = Object.entries(coursesByDate).map(([date, { courses }]) => ({
    date,
    courseCount: courses.length,
    courses,
  }));

  setEventsCountandDate(updatedCoursesCountByDate);
  console.log(updatedCoursesCountByDate);
};

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/search-course?date=09-02-2024');
      const eventData = response.data.Table1;
      countAndOrganizeEvents(eventData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to fetch events count and details', error);
    }
  };

  if (daySelected) {
    fetchData();
  }
}, [daySelected]);
```

Additionally If you want to memorize your data to avoid heavy computation on each re-render, you can use **useMemo** react hook.
The **useMemo** hook to memorize the result of the **countAndOrganizeEvents** function, preventing unnecessary recalculations when dependencies don't change. This can be particularly useful when dealing with large datasets.

Here is how you can do that:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';

// ... (your other imports)

const YourComponent = () => {
  // ... (your existing state and other code)

  const memoizedEventData = useMemo(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/search-course?date=09-02-2024');
        const eventData = response.data.Table1;
        countAndOrganizeEvents(eventData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to fetch events count and details', error);
      }
    };

    if (daySelected) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [daySelected]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Your other useEffect logic, if any
  }, [memoizedEventData]);

  return (
    // ... (your component JSX)
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Within this instance, we employ the **useMemo** hook to capture and retain the outcome of executing the **fetchData** function. The array of dependencies (**[daySelected]**) guarantees that recalculations of fetchData occur exclusively upon alterations in **daySelected**. Subsequently, the outcome of **useMemo** becomes a requisite factor in the useEffect hook, ensuring the execution of the effect when modifications to the memorized data transpire.

**Heed this advisory**: Exercise prudence when employing **useMemo** for asynchronous functions, as it yields a memorized iteration of the function itself, not the function's result. In such scenarios, opting for the direct use of **useEffect**, as illustrated in the preceding instance, may prove more judicious.

Here is the complete code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [eventsCountandDate, setEventsCountandDate] = useState([]);
  const [daySelected, setDaySelected] = useState(true);

  const countAndOrganizeEvents = (eventData) => {
    const coursesByDate = {};
    const coursesCountByDate = [];

    eventData.forEach(({ startProgramDates, endProgramDates, courseName, startTime, endTime, format }) => {
      const startDate = parse(startProgramDates, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());
      const endDate = parse(endProgramDates, 'dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());

      const uniqueDates = new Set();

      for (let currentDay = startDate; isBefore(currentDay, endDate) || isEqual(currentDay, endDate); currentDay = addDays(currentDay, 1)) {
        const formattedDate = currentDay.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' }).split('/').join('-');

        if (!uniqueDates.has(formattedDate)) {
          uniqueDates.add(formattedDate);

          if (!coursesByDate[formattedDate]) {
            coursesByDate[formattedDate] = {
              startProgramDates,
              endProgramDates,
              courses: [],
            };
          }

          coursesByDate[formattedDate].courses.push({
            courseName,
            startProgramDates,
            endProgramDates,
            startTime,
            endTime,
            format,
          });
        }
      }
    });

    const updatedCoursesCountByDate = Object.entries(coursesByDate).map(([date, { courses }]) => ({
      date,
      courseCount: courses.length,
      courses,
    }));

    setEventsCountandDate(updatedCoursesCountByDate);
    console.log(updatedCoursesCountByDate);
  };

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/search-course?date=09-02-2024');
      const eventData = response.data.Table1;
      countAndOrganizeEvents(eventData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Unable to fetch events count and details', error);
    }
  };

  const memoizedFetchData = useMemo(() => fetchData(), [daySelected]);

  useEffect(() => {
    memoizedFetchData();
  }, [memoizedFetchData]);

  return (
    // Your component JSX
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: Did you generated this answer using some tool like ChatGPT?

Comment: No, but I have used GitHub copilot to enhance the answer.